# How to use the dollar sign for jQuery without wrapping inside an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's a very common technique to write `$` instead of `jQuery` and wrap it inside a function as such:

```
(function($) {
    //Code here
})(jQuery);
```

Now, the problem with this is that, you are inside **a small, local scope** and that's good, for the most part, but if you're trying to, say, call a function name dynamically by string-construction:

```
let dynamic_name = some_function_name; //but should be dynamic, duh
window[dynamic_name]();
```

Won't work because you're operating inside that local scope, not inside the `window` scope and it will not be able to find that function, example:

```js
(function($) {
    //If we put this outside of this scope, it works.
    function test() {
        console.log('test');
    }
    let name = 'test';
    window[name]();
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This also means that if your script gets used as a library, your functions are not callable, because you're wrapping them inside an anonymous function.

Exactly how do you get around this?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Well, the problem is that it doesn't work at all.  I put in an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either assign the function to `window` explicitly:

```js
(function($) {
    window.test = function test() {
        console.log('test');
    }
    let name = 'test';
    window[name]();
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or put the function in an object instead:

```js
(function($) {
    //If we put this outside of this scope, it works.
    const fns = {
      test() {
        console.log('test');
      }
    };
    let name = 'test';
    fns[name]();
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This doesn't really have anything to do with jQuery - the same sort of behavior (and solution) can be seen in any IIFE, or any block that's not on the top level.

Comment: This works but it feels like a hack. Can you guide me to a better world when it comes to scopes / namespaces? This seems messy.

Comment: These are probably the only non-messy solutions there are. You can also use `eval` to dynamically reference something in the current scope, but that's a very bad idea. Best to avoid dynamic variable names - instead, use dynamic *property names*

Comment: I understand and it makes sense, but what is a replacement for `window` when talking about local scope? I can't use the second technique...unless...that object is a collection of these functions I'd want to call?

Comment: There is no replacement for it (un?)fortunately - outside of `eval`, there's no way to *dynamically* reference a variable in local scope. If you want to be able to dynamically look up things like that, the only real solution is to use an object. But objects are fine, there's nothing at all wrong with using them when you want to dynamically look things up

Comment: Could you please edit the answer to reflect how I'd make the object thing work? I'm having trouble understanding how I can add a function to an object then identify it.

Comment: That's what the `const fns = { test() {` is - it defines a `test` property in an object, whose value is a function

Comment: Sure, you can assign to object properties like that instead of defining the object all at once, if you wish (though it's usually nicer to use dot notation - bracket notation is  ugly-ish and is for when you can't use dot notation)